# Bootstrap 4 tooltip with dynamic title (ajax request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I assigned several bootstrap tooltips to some span elements.

I use this javascript / jquery code:

```
function tooltip()
{
 $('.tooltipelement').tooltip({
 trigger: 'click',
 title:loadtranslation
 });
}

function loadtranslation()
{
 var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
 $.post("ajax.php",{"mode" : "w1", "id" : id},function(data){
    return "x";
 });            
}
```

It doesn't work: The tooltip is not shown. If I skip the ajax request like this:

```
function loadtranslation()
{
    return "x";        
}
```

The tooltip is shown and "x" is displayed. It is not a failure on the ajax request, because I even don't evaluate the result but just return "x" as well. I guess there is a kind of time-out issue (ajax request takes several milliseconds - mayto too long for the tooltip function?)

Comment: Gah, closed with the wrong thread and now I can't close it again.  This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call if any other mod comes in here

Comment: Thanks for this link. You are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)